# Celery: how to set the status of a Task

Tags: python, celery

I have defined a Celery task like this:

```
@app.task()
def my_task():
    # Do things...
```

I'm using Flower, so I want to see the final state of the task, according to some rules created by me:

```
    if condition_1:
        return task_status_success
    elif condition_2:
        return task_status_fail
```

How can I do this?

I've seen some people do something like this:

```
class AbstractTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.last_error_log = ErrorLog(logger)
        Task.__init__(self)

    def _task_error(self, message):
        logger.error(message)
        self.update_state(state=states.FAILURE)
        raise Exception(message)
```

But that method seems to define classes as Tasks, not as functions.

Any help on how to set manually the state of a Celery task defined as a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the method you saw that uses an abstract class, you just need to pass the class as `base` to your decorator:

```
@app.task(base=AbstractClass, bind=True)
def my_task(self):
    pass
```

`bind=True` will allow you to use `self` to access the members of your class.